# How print all actors in akka system?

Tags: scala, debugging, akka

I have created akka system. Suppose there are some actors in it. How I can print all actors from akka system with their path? (for debug purposes)

Answer (score 16):

[This reply by Roland Kuhn](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/2-mruhzsc4w) suggests that this isn't a completely trivial problem, but you can get pretty close (for actors that will reply to messages in a reasonable time) using the [`Identify`-`ActorIdentity`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/#akka.actor.Identify) request-response protocol that all actors obey.

Some untested code thrown together to illustrate the idea:

```
import akka.actor._

def receive = {
    case 'listActors =>
      context.actorSelection("/user/*") ! Identify()

    case path: ActorPath =>
      context.actorSelection(path / "*") ! Identify()

    case ActorIdentity(_, Some(ref)) =>
      log.info("Got actor " + ref.path.toString)
      self ! ref.path
}
```

Comment: The one problem is that whilst this appears to request a hierarchical list, it doesn't actually generate one - child actors don't seem to get called here.

Answer (score 9):

`ActorSystem` has private method `printTree`, that you can use for debugging.

1) Private method caller (from https://gist.github.com/jorgeortiz85/908035):

```
class PrivateMethodCaller(x: AnyRef, methodName: String) {
  def apply(_args: Any*): Any = {
    val args = _args.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])

    def _parents: Stream[Class[_]] = Stream(x.getClass) #::: _parents.map(_.getSuperclass)

    val parents = _parents.takeWhile(_ != null).toList
    val methods = parents.flatMap(_.getDeclaredMethods)
    val method = methods.find(_.getName == methodName).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method " + methodName + " not found"))
    method.setAccessible(true)
    method.invoke(x, args: _*)
  }
}

class PrivateMethodExposer(x: AnyRef) {
  def apply(method: scala.Symbol): PrivateMethodCaller = new PrivateMethodCaller(x, method.name)
}
```

2) Usage

```
val res = new PrivateMethodExposer(system)('printTree)()
println(res)
```

Will print:

```
-> / LocalActorRefProvider$$anon$1 class akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider$Guardian status=0 2 children
   ⌊-> system LocalActorRef class akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider$SystemGuardian status=0 3 children
   |   ⌊-> deadLetterListener RepointableActorRef class akka.event.DeadLetterListener status=0 no children
   |   ⌊-> eventStreamUnsubscriber-1 RepointableActorRef class akka.event.EventStreamUnsubscriber status=0 no children
   |   ⌊-> log1-Logging$DefaultLogger RepointableActorRef class akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger status=0 no children
   ⌊-> user LocalActorRef class akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider$Guardian status=0 1 children
...
```

Beware, it can cause OOM If you have a lot of actors.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/untyped-actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection) you can use `ActorSelection` with a wildcard `*` to make actors send identifying messages. You can have an actor that collect the `ActorRef`s.

As mentioned by @chris-martin only actors that are not currently busy will send. A very simple actor:

```
// make all the available actor to send an identifying message
public void freeActors()
{
  ActorSelection selection =
    getContext().actorSelection("/user/*");
  selection.tell(new Identify(identifyId), getSelf());
}

...
// collect responses
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) {
  if (message instanceof ActorIdentity) {
    ActorIdentity identity = (ActorIdentity) message;
    // get the ref of the sender 
    ActorRef ref = identity.getRef();
    // the sender is up and available
   ...
```

EDIT: I know this is for Java, but it seemed helpful to me.

Comment: This only seems to provide the top level actors :/