# How do I get all actors in an actor system

Tags: java, akka

I have a actor system. I would like to log (for testing) all the actors (addresses/paths) in the system

I tried calling

```
ActorSelection actorSelection = context().actorSelection("akka://*");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(actorSelection.path()));
```

inside one of the root actors. It prints

```
[akka:, ^\Q\E.*\Q\E$]
```

But for fact I know there are more actors in my system and working. Whats the proper way to get this list ?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860939/how-print-all-actors-in-akka-system/42945462#42945462

Answer (score 2):

If it's for test purposes, I would create a dedicated `RetrieveActors` actor with this behavior (akka `v2.4.17` syntax):

```
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;

public class RetrieveActors extends UntypedActor {
    private LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    private String identifyId;

       public RetrieveActors(String identifyId) {
           this.identifyId = identifyId;
       }

       @Override
       public void preStart() {
           ActorSelection selection = getContext().actorSelection("/*");
           selection.tell(new Identify(identifyId), getSelf());
       }

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
           if (message instanceof ActorIdentity) {
               ActorIdentity identity = (ActorIdentity) message;

               if (identity.correlationId().equals(identifyId)) {
                   ActorRef ref = identity.getRef();

                   if (ref != null) { // to avoid NullPointerExceptions
                       // Log or store the identity of the actor who replied
                       log.info("The actor " + ref.path().toString() + " exists and has replied!");

                       // We want to discover all children of the received actor (recursive traversal)
                       ActorSelection selection = getContext().actorSelection(ref.path().toString() + "/*");
                       selection.tell(new Identify(identifyId), getSelf());
                   }

               }

           }
       }
}
```

And then when you want to list all your actors created, just create a new instance of `RetrieveActors`:

```
// "1" is the identifyId to make your retrieval calls unique to this actor instance
system.actorOf(Props.create(RetrieveActors.class, "1"), "LookupActor1");
```

Note that some actors may be quite long to answer if they are busy since this pattern use normal messages and mailboxes. Also, the delivery may be not guaranteed. You will retrieve only the actors that have been already created. More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/untyped-actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection).

If you need to get several times all actors in your akka system, I suggest you to modify the `RetrieveActors` behavior to perform actor retrieval in reaction of some custom message instead of doing it at initialization. This may avoid you to create several instances of the same Actor.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Identify is the right thing to do, but you have no way to know how many to wait for. Maybe subclassing your actor with a trait that allows to report their children (and then count the responses at each level) is the best approach if you want 100% correctness.

Answer (score 1):

ActorSystem has opened printTree method, so use something similar to

```
   ActorSystem<Object> actors = ActorSystem.create(...);
   System.out.println(actors.printTree());
```